# React Native Release/Production crash Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.default.Item')

Tags: ios, react-native, release

I have tried multiple solutions provided here in the StackOverflow community. But this error is happening in **iOS Release mode** only. The app is working fine in Debug mode. Also, this is not happening because of the ViewPropTypes error.

Here is the Crash Log:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.default.Item')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.default.Item'), stack:
<unknown>@1724:1312
h@2:1707
<unknown>@1635:192
h@2:1707
<unknown>@1634:97
h@2:1707
<unknown>@1614:821
h@2:1707
<unknown>@1613:137
h@2:1707
<unknown>@599:1665
h@2:1707
<unknown>@501:603
h@2:1707
<unknown>@385:743
h@2:1707
<unknown>@6:57
h@2:1707
d@2:1080
global code@1817:3
'
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "7.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.16",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.0",
    "react-native-a-beep": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1292.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-cardview": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-dimension": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.3",
    "react-native-dropdown-autocomplete": "^1.0.18",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.10",
    "react-native-fs": "2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "4.8.5",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown-v2": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-paper": "4.12.5",
    "react-native-print": "0.10.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-soap-request": "https://github.com/adamski/react-native-soap-request.git",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-tiny-toast": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.25.0",
    "react-native-xml2js": "^1.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "rmc-date-picker": "^6.0.10",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "xmldom": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "3.0.0-alpha.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use option chaining!!

Comment: @MilanJadav App is working fine in debug mode. So it is not a chaining issue.

Comment: @MilanJadav., May I know when it is happening? Is this coming after a button click? Also, What is o here?

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel it is happening right after splash screen when the JS and libraries being upacked to the memory.

Comment: I have faced some similar issue in the past where I have used some web libraries in my React-Native application due to which it was working well in debug mode but not in release mode. Check If you have any react-js specific libraries that are added. If you see global code@1817:3 line, I think this is where it is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to @Mark Tolmacs for directing me to the right path. I have finally found the solution by generating the SourceMaps. For anyone who is facing issues in the iOS or Android release build. Please perform the following steps:

**These steps are for iOS. You can modify the command for Android**

**Step 1:**

Generate the map file

`yarn react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.js --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /tmp/bundle.ios.js --assets-dest /tmp/ --sourcemap-output index.ios.js.map`

**Step 2:**

Install the Stack Beautifier library

`npm install -g stack-beautifier`

**Step 3**

Run the terminal command

`stack-beautifier index.ios.js.map -t stacktrace.txt`

Make sure you copy the error in the `stacktrace.txt` file at the route. In my case I copied the following error

```
RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.default.Item')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.default.Item'), stack:
<unknown>@1724:1312
h@2:1707
<unknown>@1635:192
h@2:1707
<unknown>@1634:97
h@2:1707
<unknown>@1614:821
h@2:1707
<unknown>@1613:137
h@2:1707
<unknown>@599:1665
h@2:1707
<unknown>@501:603
h@2:1707
<unknown>@385:743
h@2:1707
<unknown>@6:57
h@2:1707
d@2:1080
global code@1817:3
```

and the command returned me error in human-readable text

```
JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.default.Item'), stack:
  at ./node_modules/rmc-picker/lib/Picker.native.js:32:34
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at require (./node_modules/rmc-date-picker/lib/DatePicker.js:35:14)
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at require (./node_modules/rmc-date-picker/lib/index.js:7:18)
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at _r (./app/routes/InboundConfirmation/InboundConfirmation.js:20:0)
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at r (./app/routes/InboundConfirmation/index.js:3:0)
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at _r (./app/config/routes.js:92:0)
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at _r (./app/config/Layout.js:12:0)
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at _r (./App.js:21:0)
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at r (./index.js:6:0)
  at factory (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:339:4)
  at loadModuleImplementation (./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:200:20)
  at <unknown>
```

**EDIT**

You can also try the official way to generate the SourceMaps [given here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/sourcemaps)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is much too vague, so you'd need to enable sourcemaps to diagnose the issue. In your project root folder open up the `ios/.xcode.env` file and add the SOURCEMAP_FILE environment variable to the end of it:

`export SOURCEMAP_FILE="$(pwd)/../main.jsbundle.map"`

Build your release project and verify that in the root folder you have the `main.jsbundle.map` file. Run the app and grab the crash log and run symbolication on it:

`npx metro-symbolicate main.jsbundle.map < crashlog.txt`

This way you can identify the exact file and line where the crash originates from. Then you can start debugging the file to understand why the object is empty in release mode.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. However, I am unable to find the `ios/.xcode.env` file in the project folder. I have checked the hidden files as well. However, I have found another way of setting environment variables in the Xcode [here](https://m25lazi.medium.com/environment-variables-in-xcode-a78e07d223ed). Do you think this will be the same?

Comment: THANK YOU for giving the right direction towards solving the problem. However, I have taken a little bit different path. Enjoy your bounty reward. Cheers ;)

Comment: Glad it helped!

For posterity's sake: If you started your project with an older React Native version and later upgraded to 0.7x you might be missing some files, even though you can build the project. Upgrading React Native has gotten better over the years, but it's still a complicated and error-prone process. This upgrade tool can be helpful (if not a perfect solution): https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Comment: Yes @Mark Tolmacs, I did upgrade my project from React Native version 0.63.1 to 0.70.0 this could be the reason for the missing files.